# Нужно, чтобы GItBash по умолчанию всегда открывал ветку Master

Tags: git, git-bash

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Сейчас он открывает все от имени ветки style, которая была в проекте, который я давно удалила, но эта ветка style теперь преследует меня

Comment: `git remote set-head origin  master`, если я правильно понимаю "открыть по умолчанию"

Comment: error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: может быть просто нет ветки мастер. `git branch -a` все расскажет.

Comment: вопрос откуда вообще style нарисовалась)) Разве мастер это не основная рабочая ветка по умолчанию?

Comment: на git branch -a не отрегрировал, вернул к изначальной ситуации

Comment: что значит "не отреагировал"? эта команда покажет список веток.

Comment: добавила скрин в изначальный вопрос, сюда не добавлялся

Comment: Репозиторий пустой что ли?

Comment: D-side, пустой, и ветка мне эта не нужна

Comment: тогда просто git checkout -b "master"

Comment: спасибо!!!! А style все же как удалить?

Comment: Судя по выводу `git branch -a` её и нет. То есть, она существовала исключительно в виде "создастся при коммите", но поскольку коммитов в неё так и не не поступило, полноценной веткой она так и не стала, и как только вы переключились на другую, git о ней забыл.

Comment: D-side благодарю!!!